# Move a particular div out of nested divs

Tags: javascript, html, css, nested

I'm using bootstrap with nested divs but i can't find an efficient way to move out the particular div from the nest for mobile view. i only find a way with css by doing display block when pc view and display none in mobile display view and vice versa to resolved this, but it will do a bad request from database.

(I only know a CSS-Tricks method which creates 2 C divs at different positions.)

default

```
.c1{
display:block}
.c2{
display:none}
```

media queries mobile

```
.c1{
display:none}
.c2{
display:block}
```

updated progress:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      var ravenous = function() { 
            if (window.matchMedia('(max-width: 768px)').matches){
                $(".wrap_content").remove();
                $("<div class='extraDIv'></div>").appendTo(".events_wrap");
                $("<div class='top_mid col-lg-12 followmini'>as</div>").appendTo(".extraDiv");
                }
            else{
                $(".extraDIv").remove();
                $(".wrap_content").appendTo(".events_wrap");
                }
  };
    $(window).resize(ravenous);
    ravenous();
```

});

> it's just creating new dives i think, it's not moving the dives

any other better option to do this?
(meaning, i want the only 1 C div, but it is a moving div. From parent div, moving outside and become an independent div)

[image: Image link]

Comment: Why they are nested?

Comment: What is the relationship with database ??

Comment: If You using jQuery then `append()` with `matchMedia()` (this is javascript) will do the work.

Comment: @AliTorabi because i need it to be a better view

Comment: @sylvain1264 it means i have 2 C divs and it will do same request with database. it wasting and it will getting slower if have more of this nested divs.

Comment: @instead can u give me a link?

Comment: @riverrhun Can't both C divs access to same datas ? What framework are you using ?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia ?

Comment: @sylvain1264 , yes of course the C divs requesting the same datas from database. i'm scratch php, no framework.

Comment: @instead as far as i read, it just the same thing as media query, isn't it right? it's not moving any div.

Comment: That's why in mediQuery function You use `append()` function, which will move your C div wherever You want. For example `$('.a .b .c').appendTo('.new_div');`. This will move .c div into .new_div. This code You put into `mediaQuery` function Alternatively You can also use `after()` or `before()` instead of `append()`.

Comment: @instead o i see, thx for ur effort man. i will learn about this and read about this again. i will give u more question if im still confuse.. LoL :D

Comment: Do You want code snippet for that job? With media queries?

Comment: i will try until i bleed, if i bleed already i will ask the snippet from u. haha.. thx man. :)

Comment: Haha ok good luck then ;)

Comment: @instead bro, finally i'm done this problem. so i put an extra div in the container, but isn't it taking twice from database? i mean is it doubling the $_GET[] function. in original div and the extra div. please check my updated question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets say You almost there. You didn't post HTML so I'll do simple structure. With `matchMedia` it will look more like that:

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="a">
        <div class="b">
            <div class="c">This is C</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="mobile_wrapper"></div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var media_query = [
    window.matchMedia('(max-width: 768px)')
    // here You can add other medias
],
    // this is for cache purpouse
    main_wrapper = $('.wrapper'),
    mobile_wrapper = $('.mobile_wrapper'),
    nested_div = $('.c');

// this is pretty obvious I think
function media0(mq){
    if(mq.matches){
        nested_div.appendTo(mobile_wrapper); //  move c into other wrapper
    }else{
        nested_div.appendTo(main_wrapper); // move c into main wrapper
    }
}

media0(media_query[0]); // this is required to execute matchMedia first time
media_query[0].addListener(function(mq){ // event listener which is way more offective than resize() event
    media0(mq);
});
```

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/1vtk3tue/1/ 
I added background color so You can see change.

Comment: awesome man, it works like magic. never consider this. 1 more favor to ask.  do u have a link about all matchMedia for every devices? idk how to put a horizontal view and vertical view in javascript.. LoL

Comment: Media queries which works in CSS works also in JS. But if You're asking about media queries for all devices well there is many many of them see: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/
Better solution is to make media queries for resolutions customized to Your website,

Comment: ty @instead. u save my day.